# How can i add a new querystring key and value to my Request.Querystrings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request, httprequest

I have a `Request` of type `HttpRequestBase` `Collection.Request`. I am trying to add a new query string parameter in the code as shown below:

```
        var googleAnalyticsQueryString = new NameValueCollection();
        googleAnalyticsQueryString.Add("gaId", model.PageSettings.GoogleAnalyticsCode);
        Request.QueryString.Add(googleAnalyticsQueryString);
```

But i get an exception of **System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.**

how can i add this new namevaluecollection to my request ? do i have to reconstruct it ? if so, how ?

Comment: are you familiar with the following method 
`HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Add`

Comment: @MethodMan No i am not, is that what to use?

Comment: there is no `Current` object within HttpContext @MethodMan

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Add will thorw the same exception, im experiencing this now